# Sharepoint launch showing IIS not installed error

Tags: sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2007

I have installed sharepoint 2007 on my windows server. When i try to launch it through the configuration wizard, it gives this alert error:

```
Internet information services not installed
```

I have already installed IIS. Then, why is this error coming. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of IIS you are using?

If you are using Windows Server 2008 Server Manager **or** IIS7.0 then you need to provide IIS6 management capability role to work with Moss2007.

Follow these steps to resolve this issue.

- Open Server Manager, go to Roles and right click on Web Server
- And in the window that comes up, enable the option that says IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility (Installed)

Comment: Metabase compatibilty itself is not installed in my IIS. I think first i need to install it and then enable it

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Start->Turn Windows feature on or off
2. Select the following option:

   1. Internet Information Services->Web Management Tools->IIS 6 Management Compatability
   2. Tick the following:

      - IIS 6 Management console
      - IIS Metabase and IIS configuration compatibility
      - IIS Management console
      - ISS Management Service

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and these are the steps to solve it:

=> check if you have already installed IIS 6.0 compatiblity, if you don't, tick the box to get that installed and run the configuration wizard once more.
=> Assuming the first step didn't work for you go to optional features and unselect the entire branck of internet information services, this will get it uninstalled. Restart the PC
=> Go to optional features again and tick the box to install the whole branch of internet information services.

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was solved by re-enabling the "IIS Admin Service" - for some reason it was disabled

Comment: It's best to avoid speculative answers, especially on questions that have already been solved with a completely different root cause. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, please do not use answers as a workaround to help track down the cause in order to provide the solution.

Comment: It would've been disabled if you ran the powershell script supplied with CU -or- as part of Wizard where it gives the warning that services are re-started.